# Find the smallest squared integer that starts with six 2 digit

Tags: number-theory

Is there any way to find the smallest squared integer that starts with a special pattern.
For example for finding the smallest squared integer that starts with six 2 digit 222222...
I have used MatLab and find the answer but I want to solve it on paper.

Comment: See [this](https://brilliant.org/problems/inspired-by-abhay-tiwari/), I wrote up details in the solution.

Comment: may be useful if You include that number You found in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Compute $\sqrt{2.22222}$ and $\sqrt{2.22223}$.
2. Multiply them by suitable power of tens to make they have different integer parts.
3. Take the ceiling of the smaller number. 
   $$\begin{cases}
   \sqrt{2.22222} = 1.490711239643681\\
   \sqrt{2.22223} = 1.490714593743551
   \end{cases}\quad\longrightarrow\quad 1490712$$
4. Repeat step $1$ to $3$ for $\sqrt{22.2222}$ and $\sqrt{22.2223}$.
   $$
   \begin{cases}
   \sqrt{22.2222} = 4.714042850887123\\
   \sqrt{22.2223} = 4.714053457482212
   \end{cases}\quad\longrightarrow\quad 471405$$
5. Compare numbers in step $3$ and step $4$ and take the smaller one.
   This gives us $41705$ and $471405^2 = 222222674025$ is the desired answer.

Why this work? In order for the square of a number to have $6$ leading $2$s,
the number need to begin with either $149...$ or $471...$. Let's say you pick
a $6$ digit number of the form $149...$. If this number $\le 149071$, the square will be too small. If this number $\ge 149072$, the square will be too large to have the desired numbers of leading $2$s.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is really useful for me.